# Fatal error when exporting accounting batch to CSV in 4.7

Tags: issues, export, accounting, batches

Using Civi 4.7.2 (and then on 4.7.3; I thought I needed to upgrade to fix) with Drupal, I get the following error when I try to export an accounting batch to CSV:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   CRM_Financial_BAO_ExportFormat_CSV::exportACCNT() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\sites\all\modules\contrib\civicrm\CRM\Financial\BAO\ExportFormat\CSV.php
>   on line 68

I then tried both the Drupal and Wordpress 4.7 demos from demo.civicrm.org.  I added three of the demo contributions to a new batch and tried to export to CSV.  Both the Drupal and Wordpress demos white-screened.

I tried the Drupal 4.6 demo at d46.demo.civicrm.org and it successfully exported the CSV.

Did something happen between 4.6 and 4.7 for this function?  Is this a bug that needs to be reported at https://issues.civicrm.org?

Comment: This definitely merits a report on issues.civicrm.org.  Please list the steps to replicate the bug and reference this StackExchange question!

Comment: Thanks @JonG. The issue has been reported: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a bug (filed here: [issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18169](http://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18169)).  This will be corrected in Civi 4.7.4 by this pull request: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7942